# Which Starbucks coffee have the least amount of caffeine?

Tags: caffeine, starbucks

I like coffee, my mom likes coffee, my dad likes coffee, and we all love Starbucks. My question is, which coffe has the least ammount of caffeine?

I want to try to get one for my little sister :) (she's 10)

So what coffee at Starbucks has the least amount of caffeine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very probably any single-shot espresso beverage (tall Americano or latte?) prepared with decaffeinated beans or the regular decaffeinated filtered coffee is a good choice of you are looking for the coffee flavor but not very fond of caffeine.

Comment: There's also *half-caf* for roughly *50%*. Decaf is about *95%* caffeine-free.

Answer (score 2):

Regular decaf coffee from Starbucks has approx. 15mg according to this [link here.](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/the-complete-guide-to-starbucks-caffeine)

I believe you can get espresso made with decaffeinated beans, which will be lower than that due to the small amount of espresso.

If she finds that too bitter, you may be able to get an iced coffee for her made with decaf.